# Versão de Wordpress compatível com PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, wordpress

Procuro um Wordpress compatível com a versão do PHP 5.2.17.

Já garimpei no site, mas não acho requisitos das versões antigas. Minha última tentativa foi com o Wordpress 3.8.

Comment: De acordo com o [site do próprio Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), a menor versão exigida de PHP é a 5.2.4. Você está tendo problema com alguma função em específico?

Comment: Simplesmente não vai. Eu faço a configuração do banco, mas quando ele vai pro arquivo install.php ele para. Não carrega, não retorna nada. Fica nisso.

Comment: Estranho. Tenho uma página wordpress em um webhost gratuito que tem o PHP 5.2.x e funciona ok. Você fez o download dos arquivos e está seguindo o wizard de configuração, é isso? Eu segui esses passos aqui: [How to Install WordPress? Step-by-step Manual WordPress Installation Guide](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress-installation.htm), caso queira confirmar se está fazendo algo de diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o [Histórico de Lanaçamentos](http://codex.wordpress.org/History) disponível no Codex a versão que fixou o PHP 5.2.4 como sendo a versão mínima requerida foi a 3.1 (Gershwin) lançada em 2011.

Logo, por dedução, a versão 3.0 é compatível com o PHP 5.2.17, o que pode ser confirmado por [esse post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-apache-and-mysql-requirements-for-wordpress-30) no fórum do WordPress.

Quanto ao download dessa versão mais antiga, você tem o [Release Archive](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) à sua disposição.

Comment: Funcionou, era simplesmente a versão do PHP.

Comment: Oi @user7531, muito cuidado com versões antigas do PHP e do Wordpress que podem possuir erros graves de segurança permitindo ataques de Hackers.